# Dynamic insertion of data into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have tried out some code for dynamic insertion of data using array but the issue am facing is in a single row same data is been inserted and even if check box are left  un-checked data value is inserted ignoring the checked value inside a "while-loop"..I am new to this array concept please help me out.

**.php**

```
<form id="form" name ="form" method = "POST" action="move_ppl.php" class="wizard-big" autocomplete = "off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                              <div class="col-md-12">

                                        <?php
                                            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");
                                            $query = ("SELECT * FROM profile");
                                            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                                            {


                                            echo '

                                            <tr>
                                    <td align="left">' . $row['via'] . '<input type="hidden" name="type[]"  value="' . $row['via'] . '"></td>
                                    <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="macro"/>   Macro </td>
                                    <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="micro"/>   Micro </td>
                                    <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="nano"/>    Nano </td>

                                </tr>';



                                            }
                                        ?>
                                <input style="width: 100%;" type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value="Move"  class="btn btn-info"><br><br>
                                        </form>
```

**DB.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','***');
    define('PASS','***');
    define('DB','***');

    $response = array();

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["type"])){

        //receiving post parameters
             $types = $_POST["type"];
             if(sizeof($types) > 0 ){
               foreach($types as $type){
        // create a new user profile
                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO ppl_tbl (vault_no, via, gname, ppl, macro, micro, nano, created_at) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['via']."', '".$_SESSION['vault_no']."', '".$_SESSION['gname']."', '".$type."','".$type."','".$type."','".$type."', NOW())";
                                    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                                        header('Location: macro_ppl.php');

                                    }else{
                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                        $response["error_msg"] = "INSERT operation failed";
                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                    }

                }
            }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, just submit a form with data array

**Form**

```
<form id="form" name ="form" method = "POST" action="someForm.php">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="macro"/>   Macro </td>
        <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="micro"/>   Micro </td>
        <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="nano"/>    Nano </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**someForm.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['type'] as $myType) {
        echo $myType
    }
}
```

---

Your Form

```
<form id="form" name ="form" method = "POST" action="move_ppl.php" class="wizard-big" autocomplete = "off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM profile");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
?>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $row['via'] ?><input type="hidden" name="type[]"  value="<?php echo $row['via'] ?>"></td>
            <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="macro"/> Macro </td>
            <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="micro"/> Micro </td>
            <td align="left">   <input type="checkbox" name="type[]"  value="nano"/> Nano </td>
        </tr>
<?php       
        }
?>
    <input style="width: 100%;" type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value="Move"  class="btn btn-info"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but sir i require both a submit button and a while loop coz i need to display users inside a table.!

Comment: sir..can you please brief on how can i actually implement this in my code, coz i am really new to this whole concept..

Comment: sorry sir, but i see $row[] is not inside <?php tag so how can it fetch names from selected database..?

Answer (score 0):

First of all checkbox values will not be present in the post if they are not set.

Second of all you add many results cause you call insert sql in the loop.

You can use:

```
var_dump($_POST['type']);
```

so you will see how the structure actually look like.

There are many ways to make this work one could be:

```
//setting the variables first
$ppl = 0;
$macro = 0;
$micro = 0;
$nano = 0;

//then run the loop to set them
foreach($types as $type){
    if(in_array($type,['ppl','macro','micro','nano'])) //just to be sure nobody pass something else so we will not override other variables
        $$type = 1;
}

//then write the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO ppl_tbl (vault_no, via, gname, ppl, macro, micro, nano, created_at) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['via']."', '".$_SESSION['vault_no']."', '".$_SESSION['gname']."', '".$ppl."','".$macro."','".$micro."','".$nano."', NOW())";
```

Comment: and dose the form remain's unchanged??

Answer (score 0):

In PHP file

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['type'] as $value) {
      echo $value; 
      /*add this in the query, this will return the value of checkbox which are checked*/
   }
 }
```

}